# Call a value customer page

Tags: php, number-formatting

I have design a webpage to and make all necessary code in admin section. How do I call this value to show on the customer page in the number format?

I am trying to show the amount in double eval. I mean $750,100.15.
When a customer logs in the value will be shown on their page. I used the following code it work.

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['hlmgt_user']['amount']; ?>
```

This prints out `$750100.15`, but I need it to print `$750,100.15`. I am using the above code to call the value on customer page.
How to fix the below code to get it working?

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['hlmgt_user']number_format($row['balance'], 2); ?>
```

Comment: hi are you using PHP?

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: The code was hidden because of the missing indentation. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look about the "number_format" or "money_format" function in PHP here:

https://php.net/number_format

https://php.net/money_format

Answer (score 0):

try this maybe helpful

```
<?php
$number = "750100.15";
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%(#10n', $number) . "\n";
?>
```

***OUTPUT***

```
$ 750,100.15
```